# Django Import Model Error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have Created an App inside my project folder, in the same directory where manage.py exists.
i have also created model for my app, when i import it in python shell like Import Poll
it gives this error:

```
ImportError: No module named poll
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your app name is 'App' you have to type:

```
from App.models import Poll
```

in order to successfully import your Poll model. Change `App` with your current application name

Also, two things to bear in mind

1) `Poll` is different from `poll`: check that your capitalization is consistent with your model definition

2) You should have created the app using [django startapp](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination) command. If not, at least make sure you have an empty `init.py` file inside your `App` folder.